# How do I Show that, $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+}x^{x^{x^x}} = 1$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, indeterminate-forms

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}x^{(x^{(x^{x})})}$$

I tried to solve them by:

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\ln(x^{(x^{(x^{x})})}) = \lim_{x\to 0^+}x^{(x^{x})} \ln(x)$= \lim_{x\to 0^+}x^{(x^{x})} \cdot \lim_{x\to 0^+}\ln(x)$$

and then ends up with $0 \cdot -\infty $ (undefined)

I tried to render the graph in a web application and it shows that the result should be $1$, not undefined

What is the correct strategy to solve this limits?

Comment: Hint $ \lim_{x\to 0^+}x^{x} \cdot \lim_{x\to 0^+}e^{xln(x)} = 1$

Comment: If $\lim f(x) = 0$ and $\lim g(x) = -\infty$ then $ \lim f(x)*g(x)$ is not necessarily "undefined" so much as "indeterminable by this method".   Perfect example is $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = -\frac 1x$.  $\lim f(x)g(x)=-1$ is obviously not undefined.  SO you have gotten an error.... You just don't have a solution.  So you have to try something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hin

$ \lim_{x\to 0^+}x\ln x=0$ that is ${x\ln(x)}$ stay ner zero as $x$ is close to zero

so by Taylor expansion of first oder near zero give

$$ x^x= e^{x\ln(x)} \sim 1+x\ln x \implies x^{x^x} = e^{x^x\ln(x)} \sim e^{(1+x\ln x)\ln(x)} = e^{\ln x+x\ln^2 x} =x e^{x\ln^2 x}$$

That is near zero we have 
 $$\bbox[yellow]{x^{x^x}  \sim  x e^{x\ln^2 x}} $$

But $$ x\ln^2x = [\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{x}\ln\sqrt{x}]^2\to 0 \qquad as\qquad x\to 0^+$$

Therefore, near zero we have 
 $$\bbox[yellow]{x^{x^x}  \sim  x e^{x\ln^2 x}\sim x  \qquad as \qquad x\to 0^+}$$ 
Hence,

$$x^{x^x} \sim x\implies \lim_{x\to 0^+}x^{x^{x^{x}}} =\lim_{x\to 0^+}e^{x^{x^{x}}\ln(x)} \sim \lim_{x\to 0^+}e^{x\ln(x)} = 1$$

Comment: Aren't you assuming that $x^{x^{x^x}}=(x^x)^{(x^x)}$ here? That is not true.

Comment: yes I do . is there something wrong with taht?

Comment: There is the thing wrong with it that it is not true! For example, for $x=2$ we have $$2^{2^{2^2}}=2^{2^4}=2^{16}=65536 \quad\text{but}\quad (2^2)^{(2^2)} = 4^4 = 256$$

Comment: @GuyFsone $x^{(x^x)}\neq (x^x)^x$

Comment: Thank you so much for this nice remark that was mistake in which I always fall into. But now it should be alright

Comment: Thanks you very much Guy fsone

Answer (score 0):

Here is a detailed expansion in $0^+$ and justification of the chain $x^{x^{x^x}}\sim x^{x^1}\sim x^x\sim 1$

- $\lim\limits_{x\to 0+}x^\alpha\ln^{\beta}x=0$ for $\alpha,\beta>0$
- $\exp(1+u)=1+u+o(u)$ when $u\to 0$

$\begin{array}{ll}
f(x) &= x^x \\
&=\exp(x\ln x)\\
&=1+O(x\ln x)&\sim 1\\
\end{array}$

$\begin{array}{ll}
g(x) &= x^{x^x}=x^{f(x)} \\
&=\exp(f(x)\ln x)\\
&=\exp(\ln x+O(x\ln ^2x))\\
&=x\exp(O(x\ln^2 x))\\
&=x(1+O(x\ln ^2x))\\
&=x+O(x^2\ln^2x)&\sim x\\
\end{array}$

$\begin{array}{ll}
h(x) &= x^{x^{x^x}}=x^{g(x)}\\
&=\exp(g(x)\ln x)\\
&=\exp(x\ln x+O(x^2\ln^3 x))\\
&=1+x\ln x+O(x^2\ln^3 x)&\sim 1\end{array}$

*Note: $\frac 12x^2\ln^2 x=o(x^2\ln^3 x)$ so this term does not appear in the last line of $h(x)$ expansion.*

Comment: thanks for the solution and explanation, zwim